# It is related to a query in sql

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Given a database schema: `students(rollno int, hostel int, parent_inc int)` what can be the best way to select the `rollno, hostel no, parent_inc` of a student who has the max parental income in a hostel?

I had written the following query:

```sql
SELECT rollno, hostel,parent_inc
FROM students
WHERE parent_inc IN (select max(parent_inc) from students group by hostel);
```

This however has a problem.

In an instance, if the max. parent_inc among students in Hostel *9* is *x(say)* and the max. parent_inc among students in Hostel *8* is *y(say)*, where (y>x).

Now, coincidentally, if there is a student in Hostel 8 who also has parental inc *x*, then the above query will display that as well, in addition to displaying the roll nos of students who have parental incomes *x* and *y* for hostels 8 and 9. That is incorrect.

Can someone please help me out with this one?

Comment: provide some sample data and your expected output

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you wanted. For each row in your outer select you should compare its `parent_inc` value to the `max(parent_inc)` for the same hostel (only) in your inner select. Use `where` clause in your inner select. You can reference the outer row in your inner select using aliases.

```
with students as (
select *
from
    (values (1, 1, 100000),
            (2, 1, 50000),
            (3, 2, 200000),
            (4, 2, 250000)
    ) t (rollno, hostel, parent_inc)
)
select *
from students s
where
    s.parent_inc = (select max(parent_inc) from students ss where ss.hostel = s.hostel)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I wasn't handling the alias at all. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row, then use `order by` and `fetch` (or your database's equivalent):

```
SELECT rollno, hostel, parent_inc
FROM students
ORDER BY parent_inc DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```